# "Tariq ibn ziyad" or "Tarif"

Tags: escritura-manuscrita

[image]

I could not understand this manuscript.

Does it say "Tariq" or "Tarif"? What is the context?

Plz

Answer (score 1):

#### Tariq

El nombre se repite en el párrafo de la derecha:

[image]

> Quando el Rey Rodrigo el postrímero Rey de los godos fue perdido en la batalla de Sangonera y los xanos(?) desbaratados y vencidos, entonces entró **tariq** con el poder de los moros en España.

---

The character "f" is formally well defined in the following words:

- *fijo* [image]
- *fue* [image: fue]
- *fueron* [image: fueron]
- *falta* [image: falta]

and none of them match the character [image: q]

---

[image]

<sub>*Source [National Geographic](https://historia.nationalgeographic.com.es/a/batalla-guadalete_6310)*</sub>